# Problems sending two goals

Tags: ros, 2d-nav-goal, publish, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im using the simple_navigation_goal and i need to first send a goal to 7,2 (x,y) and then when he arrives he need to go to 10,4.  the problem is that i dont understand if the second goal i send must be 10,4 or 3,2.  Also when i give the robot a goal does this goal start from when the robot is, or does it represent a place in the map where it does not change when the robot moves?
I need to send my robot to a goal x,y and before he arrives i need him to go to 10,4 y have the /pose so i know where he is but dont know if the goal i must send is 10,4 or one related to the actual position posted by /pose

Any help would be really apprciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145231/problems-sending-two-goals/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The goals for the navigation stack are in the global frame, which is usually the  /map frame. This means that you'll always send the absolute goal, in your case 7,2 followed by 10,4.

You can use the [actionlib interface](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Action_API) to the navigation stack to request navigation to the first goal, and get notified when the robot arrives there, so that you can send the next goal.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest option certainly is sending all goals in the global "/map" frame. Note that you also can send goals relative to arbitrary frames (for example relative to the robot in the "base_link" frame). The goal will always be converted to the global frame inside move_base first (see [move_base.cpp line 648](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L648)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2014-03-28**:
@ahendrix @Stefan Kohlbrecher
Im puching the goals with this code
goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = 10.0;
goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = 4.0;
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
ROS_INFO("Sending goal");
ac.sendGoal(goal);

But when i see the /move_base/current_goal i see at the beguining the 7,2 but then i send the goal 10,4 as describes above the result i get in move_base/current_goal is NOT 10,4 but other number

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-03-30**:
Do you set the goal frame_id?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2014-04-01**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher im not sure, where should this be done? I followed the simple_navigation_goals tutorial